# in rails, how to titleize the string anytime user.name is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm guessing this one is very simple but I'm just not sure how to google for it.

I have a User model with a Name column where name is a lowercased string. I want to configure my model so that string.titleize is called any time the name value is retrieved.

currently:

```
user = User.find(89)
user.name
==> 'larry david'
```

but i want

```
user.name
==> 'Larry David'
```

I want this built into the model so that I don't have to call '.titleize' in all of my views

thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Override Rails' attribute accessor method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name
     read_attribute(:name).try(:titleize)
  end
end
```

**Note:** The `try` method will silently avoid a `NoMethodError` exception when the name attribute is `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

If it is only the views you are concerned about why not override the `to_s` method in your `User` model?

```
def to_s
  self.name.titleize
end
```

Then in the views `<h1><%= @user %></h1>` would be titleized.